# Statements in if statement with false condition are executed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created this guard function:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION checkTableExists (tableName varchar2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS c INT;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM user_tables where table_name = upper(tableName);
    return c = 1;
  END;
```

I try to use it like:

```
IF checkTableExists ('NO_TABLE') THEN
    DELETE FROM NO_TABLE;
END IF;
```

Even though the table doesn't exist, I get:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 17:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

How do I get around this? Dynamic SQL?

UPDATE: I get no error if I run:

```
IF checkTableExists ('NO_TABLE') THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('argh');
END IF;
```

And `argh` is not output. If I run the above with a table that does exist, `argh` is output as expected.

Comment: You would get this error if `user_tables` does not exist.  Are you sure that table exists?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my answer to show how I can exercise the if statement by outputting text, so `user_tables` must exist.

Comment: also the name of a function that you define and that you are calling a not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a guard function; just try to delete the table and catch the exception if it does not exist:

```sql
DECLARE
  table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( table_not_exists, -942 );
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM no_table';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'deleted' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN table_not_exists THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'did not exist' );
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7edec6a9076ef50423442c44dff377e3)

If you don't want to initialise the exception in lots of different PL/SQL blocks then initialise once it in a package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE exceptions IS
  table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( table_not_exists, -942 );
END;
/
```

and the code is then simply:

```sql
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM no_table';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'deleted' );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN EXCEPTIONS.table_not_exists THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'did not exist' );
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1591ca43dc8baf36f7fd6bf49d83940)

---

If you do want to use your guard function (I'd advise that you don't) then just use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
IF checkTableExists ('NO_TABLE') THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM NO_TABLE';
END IF;
```

Comment: I would need to duplicate the logic in dozens of places and rely on other developers to copy and paste this properly moving forward. I really would prefer a function. If you have guidance as to why you would disfavour a re-usable function, I'd be interested to hear it as Oracle most definitely is not my wheelhouse.

Comment: @MisterEpic You can initialise the exception in a package and then the code reduced to just catching the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is parsed completly. So if you replace

```
DELETE FROM NO_TABLE;
```

by

```
null;
```

your statement should work. 
Your error message was a little bit misleading because in line 6 is the select on user_tables and the delete is in line 2 in a different statement. This makes it harder to debug.

So you have to use dynamic sql:

```
execute immidiate 'delete from ' || 'NO_TABLE';
```